# How to test docker image with external script

Tags: testing, docker

Assume that I have a code repo. That code repo has the following files in it:

- Dockerfile
- test.sh

lets say I now build a docker image from the Dockerfile

```
docker build -t my-image .
```

Now I want to execute the test.sh in the context of my-image in a container, yet I don't have added test.sh to the docker image during build.

How do I run the docker image and execute the test.sh in it? Do I have to mount the repo as volume first or is there a quicker way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of options:

- Copy it in (`docker cp test.sh <container_id>:<path_file_should_go_inside>`) - but then you gotta run the file as a separate step
- Mount it in (`docker run -v $(pwd)/test.sh:<path_file_should_go_inside> my-image <path_file_should_go_inside>`)

Answer (score 1):

If test.sh is not part of image then you will have to mount the local repository as a volume.

```
docker run -v /path/to/local/repo:/tmp my-image /tmp/test.sh
```